# Authenticate on client side, How to protect my Java Rest API now?

Tags: java, javascript, api, rest, google-oauth

I have a web application that runs a Java Rest API (Jersey and JAX-RS) on the server side and basic JS + Angular on the client side. The user logs in with google as shown below,

```
this.handleClientLoad = function () {
        gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
        gapi.auth.init(function () { });
        this.checkAuth();
        deferred = $q.defer();
        return deferred.promise;
    };

    this.checkAuth = function() {
        gapi.auth.authorize({ 
            client_id: clientId, 
            scope: scopes, 
            immediate: true, 
            cookie_policy: cookies,
            hd: domain 
        }, this.handleAuthResult);

    };


    this.handleAuthResult = function(authResult) {
        if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
            var data = {};
            gapi.client.load('oauth2', 'v2', function () {
                var request = gapi.client.oauth2.userinfo.get();
                request.execute(function (resp) {
                    user.email = resp.email;
                    user.uid = resp.id;
                    user.name = resp.name;
                    this.loggedIn = true;              
                    //deferred.resolve(data); 
                    user.getUser().then(function(data){
                        //add user loc to loc
                        user.loc.lat = data.lat;
                        user.loc.lon = data.lon;
                        user.loc.radius = data.radius;
                        user.loc.set = true;
                        user.loc.inDB = true;
                        // start loading the book list
                        deferred.resolve(data);
                    }, function(err){
                        user.loc.inDB = false;
                        user.loc.set = true;
                        deferred.resolve(data);
                    });
                });
            });
        } else {
            this.loggedIn = false;
            deferred.reject('error');
        }
    };
```

After this, we have the user info that we need, but any Rest Client could make a request in our API. The only thing we did so far to (roughly) protect it is sending the user Google ID through the request and querying with the id as a filter. However, I know it is not the most adequate way to do so.

I've been trying to understand how it's been done with OAuth and getting tokens, but it seems that token comes once, when the user consents his/her info.

How can I get something from Google, in the front end, to create a request in the back end and confirm that this user is real?

I've been struggling quite a lot with this and I don't think it should be that hard.

Thanks!

Comment: You should make your server side get the token from Google and send it back to the frontend after a valid login, after that you can send it along in the HTTP header with future requests and have your server side validate if that token is trusted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you want to get familiar with OAuth 2. Here is a good introduction tutorial:
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/oauth2/index.html

As opposed to the comment above you don't want to have the server get the token from Google. This is because your end users won't want to type their Google credentials into your web page. So, you must use the Google auth on the front end so users have a GUI they can trust.

Once the user authenticates on the client side using OAuth 2 they will receive a token. Your client should submit the token to your ReST API. The first thing your server should do is validate that token.

Finally, your server can then even generate your own custom token if necessary to add more information to the token.